# bash when is a variable read during a fucntion or loop

Tags: bash

In a bash script lets take the extreme below examples where the call/start of the `myFn()` is 5 minutes before the echo of `$inVar -> $myvar` happens. During this time between the function start and the interaction with the `$myvar`, it is updated.

```
myvar=$(... //some json 
                alpha=hello )
 myFn(){
   local -n inVar=$1     
  //wait for 5 mins .... :)
  echo $inVar
}

myFn "myvar"

if [ -z $var ]
then
  //wait 5 mins
  //but life goes on and this is non blocking 
  //so other parts of the script are running
  echo $myvar
fi

myvar=$(... // after 2 mins update alpha
                alpha=world
          )
```

As the `$myvar` is passed to `myFn()`, when is `$myvar` actually read,

1. at `myFn` call time (when the function is called/starts)
2. at the reference copy time `inVar=$1`
3. when the `echo $inVar` occurs

and is this the same for other types of processes such as `while, if` etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting inVar as a **nameref**, so the value is not known until the variable is expanded at the `echo` statement

**HOWEVER**

In your scenario, myFn is "non blocking", meaning you launch it in the background. In this case, the subshell gets a copy of the *current* value of `myVar` -- if myVar gets updated subsequently, that update is happening in the *current* shell, not the *background* shell.

To demonstrate:

```sh
$ bash -c '
  fn() { local -n y=$1; sleep 2; echo "in background function, y=$y"; }
  x=5
  fn x &
  x=10
  wait
'
```

```
in background function, y=5
```

TL;DR: namerefs and background processes don't mix well.